# IFrame and iOS Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I've got an IFrame calling in an HTML page on a different domain/server that is giving me issues only on iOS devices. I'm trying to use a carousel and that is what is breaking the page. As soon as I include my JS file that handles the carousel the site no longer stays within the container and instead stretches to a couple thousand pixels wide and puts the content in the middle.

I've tried using a couple different carousel options such as Slick and Owl but still get the same result. I've tried putting the IFrame inside a container and setting a defined width but it still stretches past it's container once I include a JS file to handle the carousel.

Again this only on iOS devices and I've tried using Safari and Chrome. Works just fine on desktop and Android devices.

Comment: Could you post enough of the code for us to see the issue?

Comment: This project is simply using nocode https://github.com/kelseyhightower/nocode XD